# A tetrahedron with known vertex coordinates is rotated and translated; knowing the coordinates of three transformed vertices, find those of the fourth

Tags: geometry, vectors

I have an non-degenerate tetrahedron $ABCD$. I have the coordinates for all four points. The tetrahedron is then rotated and translated to become $A_1 B_1 C_1 D_1$. I know the coordinates for $A_1$, $B_1$, and $C_1$. How do I calculate the coordinates of $D_1$?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/XZF1XBP.jpg]

I am trying to define D as the sum of vectors representing the other three vertices.

Comment: Send the data, at least

Answer (score 3):

There is a unique representation $\vec{AD} = a \vec{AB} + b \vec {AC} + c \vec { AB } \times \vec {AC}$ for some constants $a,b,c$.

Then, $ \vec {A_1 D_1} = a \vec{A_1B_1} + b \vec {A_1C_1} + c \vec { A_1B_1 } \times \vec {A_1C_1}$.
So we can can calculate $D_1$

---

Notes:

- This approach also allows for cases where the tetrahedron is scaled.

Comment: [+1] Little typo: replace the last $D_1$ by $C_1$.

Comment: You should say maybe that $a,b,c$ are obtained by solving an (invertible) system.

Comment: @JeanMarie Fixed. There are various ways of finding $a,b,c$, and I don't see a reason to force a particular path. In 3-D, if $ AB \not \parallel AC$ are non-zero vectors, then any other vector has a unique representation in terms of $ AB, AC, AB \times AC$.

Comment: At the risk of "forcing a particular path" :) ... Note that, for vectors $s$, $u$, $v$, $w$, the eqn $$s=\alpha u+\beta v+\gamma w$$ is solvable by "dotting-through" w/appropriate cross products. Eg, we get $\alpha$ via the dot product w/ $v\times w$; the last two terms vanish, leaving
$$s\cdot(v\times w)=\alpha\;u\cdot(v\times w)$$
Likewise, $$s\cdot(w\times u)=\beta\;v\cdot(w\times u) \qquad s\cdot (u\times v)=\gamma\;w\cdot(u\times v)$$ Conveniently, the [triple scalar products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Scalar_triple_product) on the right are equal, saving calculation.

Comment: Thanks Calvin. If there is no scaling, are a,b and c equal to 1?

Comment: Also, can I clarify, does this work for an irregular tetrahedron?

Comment: @JustinWong 1) No, $a, b, c$ have to be determined from the values of $A, B, C, D$. 2) I didn't assume regular tetrahedron, so yes it does work for an irregular tetrahedron.

Comment: @Blue Haha, yea that's my favorite ways of determining (unique) coefficients in vectors, in part because it makes a lot of "calculate this coefficient" proofs more trivial.

Comment: Does a = AD.AB/|AB|?